# Using Spring DI and Interface default method

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-ioc

Is it safe to use Spring DI + interface default method approach, instead of classic Spring DI + interface + class?

```
@Service
public interface MessagesService {

    default public void send() {

    }
}
```

OR

```
public interface MessagesService {

    void send();
}

@Service
public class MessagesServiceImpl implements MessagesService {

    @Override
    public void send() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that you can't invoke the `default` method unless you provide an implementation for the `MessagesService`, 
so, it all depends upon where you wanted to place the `send()` method i.e., if `send()` algorithm is common to many implementations then you can keep the `send()` method as a `default` method inside the interface, otherwise it will be very specific to the `MessagesServiceImpl` class.

In simple words, it is **nothing to do** with **Spring** DI.

I suggest you read [here](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj7jI3dqZjZAhUrLsAKHTepBBMQFggpMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fjava%2FIandI%2Fdefaultmethods.html&usg=AOvVaw2gQ0hyWRnuYcjZVKAoA3tc) and understand the concept of `default` methods.

Comment: In application MessagesService interface will have only one implementation MessagesServiceImpl.

Comment: If you see that `send()` is reusable across various implementations for future then it can be `default`